# How to extract values from a string in BigQuery and assign a position number?

Tags: google-bigquery

My data currently looks like this:
[image: Initial data]

My desired output is this:
[image: New data format]

The desired achievements are:

- Extract the values in the .csv string in OrderDescription.
- Present them in a normalised table and assign and OrderDescriptionPosition which is the order it was presented in the .csv string in the original data.

I have done this by using the split function in combination with row_number. This seem to work on a Customer by customer basis but seem to return unreliable "shuffled" row_numbers when running over multiple customers, i.e. incorrect order.

```
select
   CustomerID,
   OrderID,
   OrderDescriptionItem,            
   row_number() over(partition by CustomerID, OrderID) as OrderDescriptionPosition
from
(
    select
       CustomerID,
       OrderID,          
       split(OrderDescription, ',') as OrderDescriptionItem
    from
       InitialTable
) as e
,unnest(OrderDescriptionItem)   as OrderDescriptionItem
```

Does anyone have a more robust solution? Any suggestions of using UDF and javascript ar welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WITH OFFSET` in combination with `UNNEST` to get the positions. Here is an example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 1 AS CustomerID, 1001 AS OrderID, '12,14,16,22,28' AS OrderDescription UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS CustomerID, 1002 AS OrderID, '1,5' AS OrderDescription UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS CustomerID, 1003 AS OrderID, '44,55,66' AS OrderDescription
)
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  OrderID,
  OrderDescription,
  off + 1 AS OrderDescriptionPosition
FROM Input
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(OrderDescription)) AS OrderDescription
  WITH OFFSET off;
+------------+---------+------------------+--------------------------+
| CustomerID | OrderID | OrderDescription | OrderDescriptionPosition |
+------------+---------+------------------+--------------------------+
| 1          | 1001    | 12               | 1                        |
| 1          | 1001    | 14               | 2                        |
| 1          | 1001    | 16               | 3                        |
| 1          | 1001    | 22               | 4                        |
| 1          | 1001    | 28               | 5                        |
| 2          | 1002    | 1                | 1                        |
| 2          | 1002    | 5                | 2                        |
| 3          | 1003    | 44               | 1                        |
| 3          | 1003    | 55               | 2                        |
| 3          | 1003    | 66               | 3                        |
+------------+---------+------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if your example in question represents your real use-case (in a sense of OrderDescription being an ordered list of values) - you can use your version of the query almost as is - just add ORDER BY inside OVER() as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH InitialTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS CustomerID, 1001 AS OrderID, '12,14,16,22,28' AS OrderDescription UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1002, '1,5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1003, '44,55,66'
)
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  OrderID,
  OrderDescription,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID, OrderID ORDER BY OrderDescription) AS OrderDescriptionPosition
FROM InitialTable, UNNEST(SPLIT(OrderDescription)) AS OrderDescription
-- ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderID, OrderDescriptionPosition
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mikhail. Maybe I should have clarified in my example that the order of the "OrderDescription" is not always ascending and the position in the .csv string is very important. 

OrderDescription = (6, 1, 400, 43) should return two columns: 

OrderDescription [6, 1, 400, 43] and OrderDescriptionPosition [1, 2, 3, 4]